# Merge a sequence of tuples into another sequence in scala

Tags: scala

I have a sequence of tuples like below. Number of "x" and "y"s occurred in documents "abc" and "xyz"

```
Seq(("abc", Map("x" -> 1, "y" -> 2)), ("xyz", Map("x" -> 2, "y" -> 1)))
```

How can I create an output like below from this above sequence.

```
Seq(("x", Map("abc" -> 1, "xyz" -> 2)), ("y", Map("abc" -> 2, "xyz" -> 1)))
```

Comment: you might want describe how you expect your output based on input?

Comment: Yes. I will edit the question.

Comment: Does the order of first-level keys `x` and `y` actually matter in the output? The maps in the input are not sorted. Should the output be sorted?

Comment: No need. Your solution looks fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
val s = Seq(
  ("abc", Map("x" -> 1, "y" -> 2)), 
  ("xyz", Map("x" -> 2, "y" -> 1))
)

val t = (for {
  (x, yvs) <- s 
  (y, v) <- yvs
} yield (y, (x, v)))
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.unzip._2.toMap)

println(t)
```

This produces (up to random reordering of the unsorted keys):

```
Map(
  x -> Map(abc -> 1, xyz -> 2),
  y -> Map(abc -> 2, xyz -> 1)
)
```

Comment: Was about to post pretty much the same but slightly more verbose. TIL about `unzip`. 